# Android find out when a dialog is shown on the screen

Tags: android, dialog

I need to find the coordinates of some elements of [dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).
But before the dialog is shown on the screen, all methods return 0.
How I can find out when dialog is shown on the screen?

I mean that after **dialog.show() dialog.isShowing()** returns true, but

```
int width=mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
```

returns 0

Comment: which dialog is it fragment dialog or simple dialog ?

Comment: it is simple [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

Comment: onAttachedToWindow() or onLayoutParamsChanged may help, but you have to extend the dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to determine when the dialog is shown on the screen, could you try listening to the onShow event via setOnShowListener:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) { 
        int width = alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth(); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(width) Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
    } 
});   
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but digging on the Android dev site it looks like you may be able to extend a DialogFragment class and then get the calculations you need by overriding the onCreateView method. A little more work, but that should get you access to the full lifecycle of the dialog.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: The OP is using simple Dialog

Answer (score 0):

Im still tryin to get the size of my dialog with `.getWidth()` and `.getHeight()` i think it only works in an Activity not for a Dialog.

try this option:

```
AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

View v = a.create().getCurrentFocus();
v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
int width = v.getMeasuredWidth();
```

or this method

```
  private int getDialogWidth(Dialog dialog) 
        { 
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        dialog.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        String width = "" + dm.widthPixels ;
        return (Integer.parseInt(width));
  }
```

Comment: I need not exactly find the width of dialogue, I need find out when the dialog is shown on the screen, and then I use View.getLocationOnScreen()